# Google Maps is Slow to Load Map in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, google-maps, cordova

How do I get Google Maps to stay this way:

[image]

I don't want it to show the marker point.

My solution was to use `setTimeInterval` with `gmap.setCenter` by step 1 sec to make a `setCenter` works. When the map is in full-screen the `setCenter` function works.  But I think this solution is not good for my app.

Another detail is that the map is set so that it only appears when you click an option. So the map is hidden in another div.

I also tried to idle the event of `gmap`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need help anymore, but I give you my answer for feature the same question. 
Google Maps API v3 is designed for PC browser, which has large memory and better network (than smartphone), so it is not suitable for PhoneGap.

Google provides `Google Maps Android API v2` and `Google Maps SDK for iOS`, which are able to load maps faster, but you need to them with Java and Objective-C.

[phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) helps you to implement those Google Maps into your PhoneGap/Apache Cordova easily.

So if you try to embed Google Maps into your app next time, try it.
[image]

[phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin)